# Inserting text in image not working in PHP

Tags: php, php-7, imagettftext

My function returns the error message:

```
Call to undefined function imagettftext()
```

I've already tried every thing and won't able enable `(--with-freetype-dir=DIR)`

````
    $black = imagecolorallocate($text_im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($text_im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);
    $text = 'testing shop ,9876543214';
    // Replace path by your own font path
    $font = 'arial.ttf';
    imagettftext($text_im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);
    imagepng($text_im);```
````

Comment: Is the `gd` extension enabled? This can be checked by search calling `phpinfo()` and checking if the page contains `GD`

Comment: yes it's enabled

Comment: Did you point to the freetype-dir on your computer? ` --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib/freetype-2.1.9/`

Comment: no how to do that in mac

Comment: I added a guide as answer

Comment: Install php gd extension

Comment: gd is install but without freetype @dılosürücü

Answer (score 2):

Both GD and Freetype have to be installed, Freetype can be installed using:

```
brew install freetype
```

When the installation finishes execute the following command to get the path:

```
echo "/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/$(ls /usr/local/Cellar/freetype)/lib"
```

and then use that path in the flag:

```
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.1/lib
```

The second option is to compile PHP from scratch by following these steps:

1. Download php: https://www.php.net/downloads.php
2. Unzip the zip
3. open the terminal and navigate to the folder
4. run:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/local/bin/php \
  --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-curl \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-xmlrpc \
  --enable-soap \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-gd \
  --with-jpeg-dir \
  --with-png-dir \
  --with-mysqli \
  --with-pgsql \
  --enable-embedded-mysqli \
  --with-freetype-dir \
  --with-ldap \
  --enable-intl \
  --with-xsl \
  --with-zlib
```

5. then run:

```
make
```

6. and install it:

```
make install
```

Comment: checking i'll let you know response .

Comment: how to take 3 step.

Comment: how did you install php on your mac? Did you use homebrew? @GauravGupta

Comment: Are you using xampp or mamp? @GauravGupta

Comment: i've install php apache mysql individual

Comment: I added an alternative solution @GauravGupta

Comment: sorry it didn't help

Comment: What part fails @GauravGupta

Comment: when i take 2nd approach after make and make install every command execute perfectly but when i run my laravel project it gave me error of openssl and my composer show error on mbstring also my phpinfo data changes now there is no gd lib exists